# Authenticated ServiceStack.Redis.PooledRedisClientsManager

Tags: authentication, redis, servicestack, appharbor

How do I specify a username and password for the Redis hostname when instantiating a `PooledRedisClientManager`?

```
var _redis = PooledRedisClientManager("my.redishost.com:1234");
```

I specifically need to deploy a .NET-based ServiceStack.Redis application to AppHarbor and I'm using *Redis To Go* for Redis hosting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/Authentication

To authenticate with Redis using a password, simply pass in to the connection string using password@host syntax:

```
container.Register(c => new PooledRedisClientManager("password@host:6379"));
```

Comment: Redis auth has no concept of usernames + passwords, just passwords. RedisToGo has usernames + passwords for accessing your account, but you only need a password to authenticate with your Redis instance.

Comment: Yes! I'm using Harbour.RedisSessionStateStore and ran into the same issue of trying to pass the requireauth password in in the sessionState/providers section

Comment: As of Redis 6, there's support for username, password. Docs here: https://redis.io/topics/acl